# Extracting dates from span using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have this page:

[Tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g635747-d7289335-Reviews-Acron_Waterfront_Resort-Baga_Goa.)

For every review published there is a corresponding date in the title attribute,

check this :

```
<span class="ratingDate relativeDate" title="4 February 2017">Reviewed yesterday </span>
```

So, for every review published there is a date in the title attribute, my problem is that I am not able to fetch all the dates from the reviews.

I tried with this code:

```
def Dates():
datediv = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div.col2of2 > div > div.wrap > div.rating.reviewItemInline > span.ratingDate.relativeDate')
dateatt = datediv.get_Attribute("title")
for date in dateatt:
    print(date.text)
```

But still it does not work and I get the error of

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_Attribute'
```

Where am I going wrong?

**Edit**
Ok so now I have scraped the Usernames, Date, Title and the entire review from every page, however, in just IDLE only. I want to put the scraped data from every page to say a dictionary and export it into json or maybe directly put it into an excel sheet.

The approach with the dictionary is quite confusing as I am literally not understand how would I update different keys independently with values.

```
content = {}

def mainfunction():
#Hotel Name
hname = driver.find_element_by_id('HEADING').text


#User Names
usernames = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('scrname')
for 

#Dates
datediv = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div.col2of2 > div > div.wrap > div.rating.reviewItemInline > span.ratingDate.relativeDate')


#Review Title
titlesdiv = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('isNew')
#for titles in titlesdiv:
#print(titles.find_element_by_class_name('noQuotes').text)


#Reviews 
linkdiv = driver.find_element_by_class_name('expandLink')
linkspan = linkdiv.find_element_by_class_name('ulBlueLinks')
linkspan.click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"no_padding")))
    close1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div> span > div.ui_close_x')
    close1.click()

except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading took too much time!")


reviews = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(' div > div.col2of2 > div > div.wrap > div > div > p')
for review in reviews:
    print(review.text)


#push the contents to the dictionary



#Move to next page
nextpage()


#To follow successive pages and scrape the content
def nextpage():
    nextpage = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#REVIEWS >   div.deckTools.btm.test > div >   a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk').click()
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"pcb")))
        close2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui_close_x')
    close2.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Loading took too much time!")

    mainfunction()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datediv` is list. You need to iterate over it

```
datediv = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div.col2of2 > div > div.wrap > div.rating.reviewItemInline > span.ratingDate.relativeDate')
for dateatt in datediv:
    print(dateatt.get_attribute("title"))
```

Comment: my bad, I corrected it, however I still get the attribute error with it.

Comment: Now, I get AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get_Attribute'

Comment: @rajshastri It should be `get_attribute`, with lower case "a"

Comment: Also I have one more doubt, I scraped the contents of this particular page, like Hotel name, User Name with corresponding Review Title, Date and Review. Now what I want is that to go to next review page and scrape the contents again. I am confused as there is no goto statement so that I can go to next page and call my functions again and again

Comment: @rajshastri You need to locate the `next` button and click on it. Something like `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(next_button_locator).click()`

Comment: Please check the Edited piece of question.

Comment: @rajshastri When you find the review you need to insert it to the dictionary as value when the key should be unique (maybe the tytle?). I'm on my phone right now so I can't realy help with code. Any way, new questions should be posted as new questions, not edited into existing questions :)

Comment: cool, I have posted it in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054065/push-different-scraped-contents-into-dictionary-with-json-or-excel